# Social Sharing in Cordova Application IOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to share image particularly in WeChat and WhatsApp by using this plugin : [EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareVia('whatsapp','msg',null, 
      'images/hello.png' , null /* url */, function(e) {
   console.log('share' +e)
 }, function(errormsg){
   alert(errormsg)
 })

window.plugins.socialsharing.shareVia('com.tencent.mm','msg',null, 
      'images/hello.png' , null /* url */, function(e) {
   console.log('share' +e)
 }, function(errormsg){
   alert(errormsg)
 })
```

My app gets crashed in ios but in android it works fine.

by using another method shareViaWhatsapp:

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsApp('Message via WhatsApp' 
  ,'images/hello.png', function() {
        console.log('share ok')
        }, function(errormsg){
           alert(errormsg)
        })
```

This method working in android but in ios its showing all the apps to share when i share image, If i share only message its working properly in ios. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing to whatsApp with shareViaWhatsApp is not working on iOs also in my case I can confirm. 
Only way I was able to share picture was using share sheet with the plugin you mentioned.
So its something like:

```html
this.socialSharing.share(null, null, this.screen, null).then(() => {  
console.log(' succ share test')
  this.shareWhatsApp()
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(' err share test')
  this.shareWhatsApp()
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but you used default share sheet right